# stringified list to two separate lists

Tags: python, list

I have a stringified list that looks something like this:

```
'[a:1,b:1,c:2,a:3]'
```

I want to separate this into two lists.

`['a','b','c','d']` and `[1,1,2,3]`

is there any pythonic way of doing this without using eval (it doesnt work anyways)?

Comment: Off topic : You could keep an array to with a length of 26 and just loop through the data and increase the value at index (char[I] - 'a') and you would get the same result without a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find the characters  and numbers and `zip` function to separate them :

```
>>> a='[a:1,b:1,c:2,a:3]'

>>> import re
>>> zip(*re.findall(r'([a-z]):(\d)',a))
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('1', '1', '2', '3')]
```

Comment: a,b,c etc are actually hashes so they can also look like 14ef23 or a123hhhsb. what should i modify?

Comment: So in that case just change `[a-z]` to `\w+`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
zip(*re.findall(r'([a-z]):([0-9])', my_string))
```

Depending your use, you can also add some `+` :

```
>>> zip(*re.findall(r'([a-z]+):([0-9]+)', '[a:1,blabla:1,c:20,a:3]'))
[('a', 'blabla', 'c', 'a'), ('1', '1', '20', '3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to go a little bit further in the requirement to get a list of ints:

```
str = '[a:1,b:1,c:2,a:3]'
p,q = zip(*[(x,int(y)) for x,y in re.findall('([a-z]+):(\d+)', str)])
```